# Modulen not found in openNetMon

Tags: mininet, sdn, pox

So I've been working on SDN and im new to the field, when following the step in the github repo(https://github.com/TUDelftNAS/SDN-OpenNetMon)  I get an error saying the the module is not found: opennetmon.startup. I have tried to use the startup.py file without any success. Have any of you any tips about this or have faced the same problem? Thank you